# Is it possible to create new linked list nodes inside a loop in goLang?

Tags: loops, go, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to create a nodes for a linked list and return the head inside a Function.

Definition for each node:

```
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}
```

This is the function:

```
func addTwoNumbers(l1 *ListNode, l2 *ListNode) []string {

    calculateValue := func(l *ListNode) int {
        var sumsum int
        element := l
        weight := 1
        for element != nil {
            sumsum = sumsum + element.Val*weight
            weight = weight * 10
            element = element.Next
        }
        return sumsum
    }

    numstr := strconv.Itoa(calculateValue(l1) + calculateValue(l2))

    listsum := strings.Split(numstr, "")

    return listsum

}
```

Right now the function returns a list of strings, each string should be assigned to `Val` in each node.(Val is an integer and right now the list is of string I can handle that later).

So the idea would be to iterate through a list with a for loop and create the nodes and link them together inside a for. It would look something like this (inside `addTwoNumbers` before the return):

```
    for _, element := range listsum{
        

    }
```

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: You're trying to create linked list `calculateValue(L1) -> calculateValue(L2)` where `L1,L2` are linked lists right ? If not can you provide example of input and expected result ?

Comment: Yes 'l1'and 'l2' are linked lists. The list store the digits of a number I should add the numbers and return a linked list. An example would be: l1 stores Val 1-2-3 and l2 stores 3-3-3-4 then I should create a list which looks like this 5-5-6-3 since the list is accessed right to left.

Comment: It doesn't matter though. What I need to know is if it is possible to create new nodes inside a for loop or any other loop. It really shouldn't matter what is the type of things that are involved in doing this.

Comment: Of course its possible, `.Next` is pointer to node so just create `head := &ListNode{}`, add nodes in cycle and return `head`.

Comment: how would you do the sintax? Because I can't do it neither find how to. I tried creating a list type listNode and append to it the new nodes but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution mentioned in comment

```golang
// create head with the value from first element
head := &ListNode{ Val: listSum[0] }

tail := head
// range remaining values
for _, sum := range listSum[1:] {
    node := &ListNode{ Val: sum }
    tail.Next = node // append node to list
    tail = node // change tail pointer to currently added node
}
```